# how to use  jstraverse update

Tags: hash, node.js, traversal

I have this object.

```
var users = {
    'jane':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'jane','data':{x:100,y:100}},
    'rahul':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'rahul','data':{x:100,y:100}}
};
```

I want to update the `jane` key data by addin `{'status':'login'}`

by using the jstraverse how can i do this?
This what i have tried ?

```
var Traverse = require('traverse');
var users = {
    'jane':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'jane','data':{x:100,y:100}},
    'rahul':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'rahul','data':{x:100,y:100}}
};

var scrubbed = Traverse(users).map(function (x) {
    console.log(this.key);

    this.update({'status':'login'});
});
```

but by which function i will get the key of jane and accoring to that i update here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this i have done is it ok?

```
var Traverse = require('hashish');
var users = {
    'jane':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'jane','data':{x:100,y:100}},
    'rahul':{'sessionId':'12345','userid':'rahul','data':{x:100,y:100}}
};
console.log(users.jane);
var scrubbed = Traverse(users.jane)
    .update({'status':'login'})
    .items;
console.log(scrubbed);
users.jane=scrubbed;
console.log(users);
```